# Display character in table cell based on calculation results in another cell

Tags: reporting-services

I have a table in SSRS 2008R2 that calculates a percent value for two numbers, and places an asterisk (*) in the last column if the percent value is below .65.  This works fine in the individual rows.  However, I have to calculate the percent value for totals rows as the table is rendered (1st row, Percent column).  I need to use this value to determine whether the asterisk in the '<65%' column will show.  Can this be done, or do I need to go back into the code and derive the value there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question depends on whether the calculated cells are inside the scope of the group on which you are aggregating.  If they are inside the group scope, it is possible to derive these values in SSRS.  If not, they have to be pre-calculated in the underlying dataset.  This is because referencing of cells cannot be determined when a source cell's position relative to the derived cell is dynamically generated.